# Convert MongoDB Controller items into JSON in perl?

Tags: json, perl, mongodb, mojolicious

```
 using MongoDB;

 my $content = $db->items->find('something');
 my $json;
 while($content->next){
           push the data into a $json
 }
```

where there is a way

```
 my @variables = $content->all;
 foreach (@variables){
    push the data into $json
 }
```

Is there any way i can convert directly push the data into json string;

and push the data into Mojolicious

```
$self->render(json => $json);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote a small Mojo test script for it. Use

```
$collection->find->all
```

to get a list of all pages, not an iterator. Here's the test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite;
use MongoDB;

# --- MongoDB preparation ---

my $conn    = MongoDB::Connection->new; # create a MongoDB connection
my $test_db = $conn->test;              # a MongoDB database
my $tests   = $test_db->tests;          # a test collection

# insert test objects
$tests->remove();
$tests->insert({name => 'foo', age => 42});
$tests->insert({name => 'bar', age => 17});

# --- Mojolicious::Lite web app ---

# access the tests collection in a mojoy way
helper mongo_tests => sub {$tests};

# list all tests as JSON
get '/' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(json => [$self->mongo_tests->find->all]);
};

# --- web app test ---

use Test::More tests => 6;
use Test::Mojo;

my $tester = Test::Mojo->new;

$tester->get_ok('/')->status_is(200);
my $json = $tester->tx->res->json;
is $json->[0]{name},    'foo',  'right name';
is $json->[0]{age},     42,     'right age';
is $json->[1]{name},    'bar',  'right name';
is $json->[1]{age},     17,     'right age';
```

Output:

```
1..6
ok 1 - get /
ok 2 - 200 OK
ok 3 - right name
ok 4 - right age
ok 5 - right name
ok 6 - right age
```

Note: I couldn't use `is_deeply` to test the `$json` data structure because MongoDB adds OIDs. You'll see them when you dump `$json`.

Comment: +1. This is the right way to do it, assuming you want everything all at once.

Comment: yeah working fine, tried to figure out the monogb controller model